# When algorithm is placed inside loop it produces different results, C++

Tags: c++, r, algorithm, rcpp

I create the following algorithm in Rcpp and compile it in R.

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
#include <RcppArmadilloExtensions/sample.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]

arma::colvec Demo(arma::mat n, int K){
  
  arma::colvec N(K);
  
  for(int j=0; j<K; ++j){
    for(int i=0; i<(K-j); ++i){
      N[j] += accu(n.submat(i,0,i,j));
    }
  } 
  return N;
}

/***R
K = 4
n = cbind(c(1008, 5112, 1026, 25, 0), 0, 0, 0, 0)
Demo(n,K)

for(i in 1:3){
 print(Demo(n,K))
 print(K)
 print(n)
}
*/
```

However, something really weird happens when I run it inside a loop.

For example, if I have

```
> K = 4
> n
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,] 1008    0    0    0    0
[2,] 5112    0    0    0    0
[3,] 1026    0    0    0    0
[4,]   25    0    0    0    0
[5,]    0    0    0    0    0
```

Then if I run the algorithm `Demo` a single time I receive the correct result

```
> Demo(n,K)
     [,1]
[1,] 7171
[2,] 7146
[3,] 6120
[4,] 1008
```

However, if I run it multiple times inside a loop, it starts to behave weird

```
for(i in 1:3){
 print(Demo(n,K))
 print(K)
 print(n)
}
    [,1]
[1,] 7171
[2,] 7146
[3,] 6120
[4,] 1008
[1] 4
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,] 1008    0    0    0    0
[2,] 5112    0    0    0    0
[3,] 1026    0    0    0    0
[4,]   25    0    0    0    0
[5,]    0    0    0    0    0
      [,1]
[1,] 14342
[2,] 14292
[3,] 12240
[4,]  2016
[1] 4
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,] 1008    0    0    0    0
[2,] 5112    0    0    0    0
[3,] 1026    0    0    0    0
[4,]   25    0    0    0    0
[5,]    0    0    0    0    0
      [,1]
[1,] 21513
[2,] 21438
[3,] 18360
[4,]  3024
[1] 4
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,] 1008    0    0    0    0
[2,] 5112    0    0    0    0
[3,] 1026    0    0    0    0
[4,]   25    0    0    0    0
[5,]    0    0    0    0    0
```

In the first run, it computes it correctly, then in the second run it gives the correct output multiplied by 2, and in the third run, it gives the correct output multiplied by 3. But based on the algorithm steps, I do not see an obvious step that produces this kind of behavior.

The correct output should have been

```
for(i in 1:3){
 print(Demo(n,K))
}
     [,1]
[1,] 7171
[2,] 7146
[3,] 6120
[4,] 1008
     [,1]
[1,] 7171
[2,] 7146
[3,] 6120
[4,] 1008
     [,1]
[1,] 7171
[2,] 7146
[3,] 6120
[4,] 1008
```

Comment: What is `accu` function? Can you also print `n` in every iteration of the loop and show the results?

Comment: It is presumably `arma::accu` from [Armadillo](https://arma.sf.net).

Comment: Also, what is `IndAvel`?  Did you just rename `Demo` or is it a different function?

Comment: A [minimally complete verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would help.

Comment: @DanM. ```accu``` is like a ```sum``` function from Armadillo as stated by Dirk Eddelbuettel. Yes, I'll also print the matrix ```n``` .

Comment: @dww Nothing changes everything remains that same, both ```n``` and ```K``` remain the same. Sorry I confused the names, because ```IndAvel``` is the version that I make changes to fix the problem.

Comment: Hi @DirkEddelbuettel just a small question, I changed everything from using Armadillo syntax to standard Rcpp, with the use of  ```NumericMatrix, NumericVector``` and it fixed the problem. And because in most of your answers, at least in the questions that I have asked, you tend to use Rcpp syntax should I also prefer that or it depends on the problem??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are incrementing `N` in place via `+=`.

Your function fails to ensure it is initialized at zero.  `Rcpp` tends to do that by default (as I think it is prudent) -- but this can be suppressed for speed if you know you are doing.

A minimally repaired version of your code (with the correct header, and a call to `.fill(0)`) follows.

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::colvec Demo(arma::mat n, int K){
    arma::colvec N(K);
    N.fill(0);   // important, or construct as N(k, arma::fill::zeros)
    for(int j=0; j<K; ++j){
        for(int i=0; i<(K-j); ++i){
            N[j] += accu(n.submat(i,0,i,j));
        }
    }
    return N;
}

/***R
K = 4
n = cbind(c(1008, 5112, 1026, 25, 0), 0, 0, 0, 0)
Demo(n,K)

for(i in 1:3) {
 print(Demo(n,K))
 print(K)
 print(n)
}
*/
```

You could also call `.zeros()` (once constructed) or use `zeros(k)` (to construct) or ... deploy a number of different ways to ensure your content is *cleared* before adding to it.

The shortest, after checking the documentation, may be `arma::colvec(N, arma::fill::zeros)`.

Comment: Hi Dirk; just out of curiosity please. In the OP code why does running `Demo(n,K); Demo(n,K); Demo(n,K)` give the expected results but running it in a `for` loop `for(i in 1:3){ print(Demo(n,K))}` , or in fact `{ Demo(n,K); Demo(n,K); Demo(n,K) }` give weird results? Is there something in the braces that retains something in the c++ function environment?

Comment: It's all undetermined behaviour as _he is adding to uncleared memory_.  Just how _undetermined_ pans out appears to vary in your setups.  But that is irrelevant as the underlying code was faulty.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel nit: it's _undefined_

Comment: @DanM Yes, thanks, better terminology.  Cannot edit comments anymore.